# How to debug state management(Redux-RTK) using Flipper in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

what is the proper way to debug all the state management flow using redux and RTK?
within flipper ,
and all requests via RTK are will be tracked via the network tracker inside flipper ?

i would like to know if there is way to debug  and track the changes in the store

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger ?

Comment: im using Flipper at the moment